# Running headless Firefox browser in a virtualenv without install Firefox in it

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-venv, headless

I would link to know how can I run headless Firefox with Python 3 in a virtual environment without install Firefox in that environment. I have it installed in my system(Linux Mint) though. Here what I tried considering I'm inside the virtual environment.

```
pip install selenium
pip install webdrivermanager
webdrivermanager firefox --linkpath .virtualenv/bin
```

The Python script is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
print("Firefox Headless Browser Invoked")
driver.quit()
```

I'm running it with the command: python3 test.py

Bellow the error message:

```
The geckodriver version (0.29.0) detected in PATH at /home/guilherme/programming/python/ct-ero/casa-venv/.virtualenv/bin/geckodriver might not be compatible with the detected firefox version (120.0.1); currently, geckodriver 0.33.0 is recommended for firefox 120.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guilherme/programming/python/ct-ero/casa-venv/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
  File "/home/guilherme/programming/python/ct-ero/casa-venv/.virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 60, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "/home/guilherme/programming/python/ct-ero/casa-venv/.virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/guilherme/programming/python/ct-ero/casa-venv/.virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/guilherme/programming/python/ct-ero/casa-venv/.virtualenv/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64
```

Bellow the output of "pip list":

```
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
appdirs            1.4.4
attrs              23.1.0
beautifulsoup4     4.12.2
certifi            2023.11.17
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
exceptiongroup     1.2.0
h11                0.14.0
idna               3.6
lxml               4.9.3
outcome            1.3.0.post0
pip                22.0.2
PySocks            1.7.1
requests           2.31.0
selenium           4.15.2
setuptools         59.6.0
sniffio            1.3.0
sortedcontainers   2.4.0
soupsieve          2.5
tqdm               4.66.1
trio               0.23.1
trio-websocket     0.11.1
urllib3            2.1.0
webdrivermanager   0.10.0
wsproto            1.2.0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: how exactly do you plan to run firefox without firefox ?